# How do I deactivate an RDS License from a crashed licensing server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop, remote-desktop-services

One of my licensing servers crashed (SRV01).

I can't deactivate it because its down and when I open the licensing diagnoser on a server in the same RDS collection it says SRV01 is not available (obviously).

So how do I remove this licensing server so I can get my license back?

Answer (score 1):

Install RDS Role in new server or rebuild your crushed server. Then go to activate.microsoft.com and select "Manage CALs" option.
You need to give license Server ID to move you CALS.
Once server is activated your Session Host server will get pointed to new server.
Note: If you don't have License Server ID call Microsoft Clearing House and ask them to activate it. Keep your enrollment Number ready before you call